# Sorting selectbox options from database

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

I'm trying to sort my selectbox options in alphabetically ascending order. (Starting at A, going all the way to Z)

I tried using a sorter I found in another question but I can't seem to get it to work on all of my selectboxes. I tried calling the selectboxes by using document.getElementsByTagName() but that doesn't seem to work either.

This is the function I'm trying to use:

```
function sortlist() {

            var selectOptions = document.getElementsByClassName("sortList");
            var selectOptionsTexts = new Array();
            console.log(selectOptions);

            for (i = 2; i < selectOptions.length; i++) {
                selectOptionsTexts[i - 2] =
                        selectOptions.options[i].text.toUpperCase() + "," +
                        selectOptions.options[i].text + "," +
                        selectOptions.options[i].value + "," +
                        selectOptions.options[i].selected;
            }

            selectOptionsTexts.sort();

            for (i = 2; i < selectOptions.length; i++) {
                var parts = selectOptionsTexts[i - 2].split(',');

                selectOptions.options[i].text = parts[1];
                selectOptions.options[i].value = parts[2];
                if (parts[3] == "true") {
                    selectOptions.options[i].selected = true;
                } else {
                    selectOptions.options[i].selected = false;
                }
            }
        }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you sort the data while filling at the initial time

Comment: By sorting at the initial(?) time I assume you mean the same as @nusje2000? Since his answer was clearer I'll accept his, but thanks for the suggestion regardless

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using laravel and getting your data from a database as in the title, you can just sort it alphabetically once you select it from the database. you can use the Laravel Query Builder for that or the default sql methode.

Laravel Query:

```
DB::table('your_table')->orderBy('col_name', 'asc'); //asc = ascending, desc = descending
```

SQL Query:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table ORDER BY column_name ASC //ASC = ascending, DESC = descending
```

For more things about the laravel query builder you can visit the laravel documentation at: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries.

I hope this will solve your problems.